My scotch bonnet (Bonney pepper) buds won't open
I live in South Korea. In early March I planted some scotch bonnet seeds. I've had to keep the plants inside because I live in an apartment and have no way to keep them outside. It's now raining season (July) in SK and can be quite humid.
I keep the plants under a grow light for about 10-12hrs and the room temp. is about 24-27°C. I water the plants every 2 days. As it is now humid I do have the aircon/dehumidifier on for a few hours each day.
I've had buds for the last 2-3 weeks but the buds won't open. After a while they just dry up and fall off.
Not quite sure what to do to get them to open.
Will try to add pictures if possible.
Please help!


Are you fertilizing them?  If so, with what?   I wonder if the plants don't have the nutrients they need?   Also, can you take extreme close ups of the flowers - especially the one in the centre of the image - it almost looks to me like it has already flowered and is starting to grow a fruit.  (I'm fairly good with nightshades in general, but I've never grown hot chillis - so I can't tell from whats there).   Another thing you can possibly try is pruning the plant to push energy to the flowers rather then the leaves.  Commercial growers prune and provide nutrition mercilessly.

Beautiful plant. Bud blasting often stems from low humidity. Outside sun would help. Keeping the plant in a crowded pot increases flowers.

Widest possible(lowest nitrogen) fertilizer. Even more light. Watering sounds fine. Picture is horrible as it shows the leaves as white - as I trust they are not to Your eyes.
